# Execute a command as a non super user in a sudo script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I developed a script.

This script should called with sudo:

```
$ sudo ./script
```

In my script I have a command in the middle which I want to execute it as a non super user (like if it's executed without sudo)

Is it posssible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Technical it's possible with `sudo -u plain_user command` in your script. This way of scripting is somehow strange to me though.